# BMI calcuator, several methods, code check

Tags: java

It's my first program with several methods

1st has to convert height to inches

2nd calculate BMI

3rd receive BMI and and return the status

4th which is the main, has to call for input and generate output

The problem is that it doesnt calculate the BMI - it outputs 0.
When I run it in just one method, it works fine. What might be wrong?

```
package bmiCalculator;
java.util.Scanner;
public class BmiCalculator {

public static double bmi;
public static int height;
public static int feet;
public static int inches;
public static int weight;
public static String status;


  public static void convertToInches (){

    height = feet * 12 + inches;

 }
  public static void bmiCalculator (){

     bmi = (weight * 703) / (height * height);


}
    public static void weightStatus () {



        if (bmi < 18.5){
           status = "underweight"; 
         }
        else if (bmi <= 24.9){
            status = "normal";
        }
        else if (bmi <= 29.9){
            status = "overweight";
        }
        else if (bmi >= 30){
            status = "obese";
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

       System.out.println("Put your height in ft and inches"); 
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
       feet = sc.nextInt();
       inches = sc.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Put your weight in pounds");
       weight = sc.nextInt();


       System.out.println("Height: " + feet + " feet, " + inches + " inches");
       System.out.println("Weight: " + weight + " pounds");
       System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + "category" + status);

    }
 }
```

Comment: I would consider using `double` instead of `int` for all your variables, as a starting point

Comment: You also never call any of your methods

Comment: Where, in you code, do you actually "call" or "execute" those methods you've written?  In order to execute their functionality, you need to "call" them

Comment: @MadProgrammer 

public static void convertToInches (double feet, double inches, double height)

Comment: should it be like that?

Comment: The naming is not the problem, the problem is, no where in your code do you actual use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring those method does not mean all will execute. you need to call those methods from `main` accordingly.

for example:

```
   ...
   System.out.println("Put your weight in pounds");
   weight = sc.nextInt();


   System.out.println("Height: " + feet + " feet, " + inches + " inches");
   System.out.println("Weight: " + weight + " pounds");
   // call corresponding method to calculate:

   convertToInches();
   bmiCalculator();
   weightStatus();
   // now all of those method are executed.

   System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi + "category" + status);
```

Declaring all those methods and properties as static is not a good practice. Please learn how `OOP` works.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Can't believe it was that easy to fix.

Comment: Happy to help. If this solve your problem, don't forget to accept and upvote this. @martines

Answer (score 2):

first, you need to call the methods after the user enter values like this..

```
...   
System.out.println("Put your weight in pounds");
weight = sc.nextInt();

convertToInches();
bmiCalculator();
weightStatus();
System.out.println("Height: " + feet + " feet, " + inches + " inches");
...
```

The order of calling the methods is important because there are dependences between them. 
Also, you need to convert the divisor and dividend to double before the BMI division because int/int = int and java round the value.

```
public static void bmiCalculator() {
    bmi = (double)(weight * 703) / (double)(height * height);
}
```